# SQL query that will retrieve multiple records when only one meets the criteria

Tags: sql

I have a table with multiple records for each account, each record has a unit# with a balance.  I want to select the account if one of the units has a negative balance and return all records for that account including the record with the negative unit.  for example:  Acct # 1234 has two records (each having a different unit# and balance). One unit has a negative balance and one has a positive balance.  I want to retrieve both the unit records for any account where one unit is negative.
 How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What database system?

Comment: 1. What @TomH said. 2. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm new to sql so nothing so far. I've only written simple queries to this point, so I have no idea whether a nested query or CTE will work or how to code it.

Comment: using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: Can you please provide the table structure?

Comment: I use Microsoft Report Builder to write my queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `IN` will do it in standard SQL;

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE account_id IN (
    SELECT account_id FROM myTable WHERE balance < 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
Select * 
  from yourAccountTable a
 where EXISTS (select 1 
                 from yourAccountTable b
                where a.accID = b.accId
                  and b.unitBalance < 0 )
```

What the clause `exists` do is to validate in a boolean way if a given registry ( `a.accID = b.accId` ) follow some condition it is basically a JOIN operation to return rows based on conditions in your case, if the balance is negative.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your table structure to give you a more accurate query, but you can do this with a simple `WHERE EXISTS`:

```
Select  *
From    YourTable   A
Where Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    YourTable   B
    Where   A.AccountNo = B.AccountNo
    And     B.Balance < 0
)
```

This will bring back any records whose AccountNo has any Balance records of negative value.

Answer (score -1):

Not knowing what you have tried so far and what database system you are referring to: Here's one help.
Do a subquery with the criteria to limit the Accts, which will then feed into the parent query to retrieve all relevant records.

Just saw that you mentioned SQL Server 2008. I like the EXIST clause answer but again sometimes a simple subquery IN clause will give you more options:

```
    Select * 
    from yourAccountTable a
    where a.Acct IN (select distinct a.Acct 
             from yourAccountTable b
             where b.unitBalance < 0)
```

Comment: wow, lots of hints!  thanks, i'll give some of these a try and let you know.

Comment: @Tina definitely mark the answer that works the best for you.

Comment: sorry for the delay in responding, was out of the office.  I was able to make the following query work using  Joachim's suggestion.  Many thanks!